# Flutter show spinner on login

Tags: flutter, dart

Newbie to Flutter.
I am trying to create a simple login page which does an authentication on button click using the `BLOC` architecture pattern.

I have most of the piece working except one thing:

1. How do I display a `CircularProgressIndicator` in the center of the app while the login is in progress and then dismiss it once it's complete (irrespective if the call is a success or failure)?

I am seeing conflicting answers where some are recommending usage of `Streams`, `Future` or `FutureBuilder`.

My build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final logo = Hero(
      tag: 'hero',
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        radius: 48.0,
        child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
      ),
    );

    final email = TextFormField(
      controller: _usernameController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      autofocus: false,

    //  initialValue: "hello@world.com",
      validator: _validateEmail,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Email',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );

    final password = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: _passwordController,
      obscureText: true,
      //initialValue: "12345",
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Password',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );

    final loginButton = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:16, right: 16, top: 16, bottom: 5),
      child: RaisedButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
        ),
        onPressed: () {

        bloc.fetchLoginDetails(_usernameController.text,_passwordController.text).then((result){

            if(result != null && result is UserLoginModel){
              //Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HomePage.tag);
              Navigator.push(context,    MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => HomePage(name: result.response.username),
              ));
            }else {
              _showDialog(result as UserLoginErrorModel);
            }


          });
        },

        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:12, right: 12),
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        child: Text('Log In', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      ),


    );
```

Kindly note that I am trying to show a native spinner.
Thanks!

Comment: You are using wrong the BLoC pattern, because you are using an input also like output and all `inputs` need to be `sinks` and `outputs` need to be `streams`, for example here (`bloc.fetchLoginDetails...`) you can learn the BLoC design guidelines [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLHln7wHgPE&t=22m54s). I can help you to solve your problem, but first I need to see your bloc, and your bloc have to follow the BLoC design guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

you create a new variable:

```
bool checkLoginFinish = false;
```

your login function is a async function. You can use "then" after "whenComplete" .

```
bloc.fetchLoginDetails(_usernameController.text,_passwordController.text).then((result
{
.....
}).whenComplete((){
   setState(() {
      checkLoginFinish = true;
    });
});
```

Then if checkFinish is false, show CircularProgressIndicator, if not don't show and go to the new page.

```
return checkLoginFinish ? LoginPage() : CircularProgressIndicator();
```

Comment: and where exactly would i initiate the spinner within the build?

Comment: I am not trying to recreate the login page. I just want to show a spinner while auth is being done. Wouldnt the last statement redraw the UI?

Comment: Do you want to show spinning above everything in the middle?

Comment: Yes thats what I want.

Comment: You can chack this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883112/how-to-use-circularprogressindicator-in-flutter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196541/discussion-between-mehmet-akif-baysal-and-user2511882).